# Add error message without using WithMessage() method in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I have a question and would be grateful if anyone can help me.
I am validating an object with "FluentValidation" in an ASP.NET project, and I would like to know if there is a way to add an error message in "ValidationResult" without using the WithMessage () method.
I am needing to add an error message based on a condition that is not related to the properties of the validated class.
I thank the attention.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a custom validator for instance.

[see FluentValidation documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html). You can see here a screen from Visual Studio [image] where an ErrorMessage-string is added. Here's some actual code for such a rule

```
RuleFor(customerCreateCommand => customerCreateCommand.Dto.Addresses)
           .Custom((addresses, context) =>
           {
               bool includesBillingAddress = false;
               foreach (AddressDto address in addresses)
               {
                   if (address.AdressTypeId == Commons.Enums.AddressType.Billing)
                   {
                       includesBillingAddress = true;
                   }
               }
               if (includesBillingAddress == false) { context.AddFailure("A customer profile needs a billing address"); }
           });
```